# how to share this same instance of lib by two programs

Tags: java, visual-c++, dll

I wrote program in java which is using some kind of win lib and now I want to write one more program to simulate other one. I mean, it should be going like that :

- first program asking lib for some simple data ( just true false)
- and other program in this same time by using function from this lib setting some variable in this lib which might be return to first program...
- both programs are independent first (lets say "getter") in java and second ("setter") in c++... I have already set all variables in lib as static but it didn't solved problem.

Is this kind of solution even possible? or I have to use maybe some kind of socket or else

thanks for replay

Comment: If both are different programs, then I think you should go for inter process communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with this kind of stuff (Java + dll + another programs) and I can tell that the libraries executed from another program and Java doesn't share the static variables, so I think you won't be able to do it that way.

The example that I have uses a window, whose size is 0, to exchange messages between the two programs (Java and VB 6.0), the first call between the two programs share the window handler, but I think this isn't the best way to do it, and, in addition, it has some limitations.

I expose the ways I think that could match your problem:

- Shared file: pretty easy, just must take care with the encoding.
- Memory area: You can use in the dll a memory area for data exchange, this is a truly "static" context
- Socket: Maybe is the most flexible since it will work with any program/system.

The last one would be the one that I'll use if I must implement something like that, but that depends on you.

Comment: thanks for answer... Ive spend few more hours to solve this problem and ive choose socket and work well quite fine...
i couldnt use shared file cose main program(java) asking library every 10 ms and and program to simulate hardware box sending signal every 10 ms to simulate more/less "normal cable" communication 

anyway thank you for your answer cose it make me sure i did right :)